# Type specialization; how to determine and react on each specific type?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, types, specialization

Imagine that I have a general class `Person`. Then I have specializations of that class, for example `DanishPerson` and `BritishPerson`.

Now I need a function that returns the correct instance of Persons, depending on what country they are in, or a way to easily determine what type of persons they are. So I have the function:

```
List<Person> GetPersonsByCountry(int countryId)
{
    // query database, and get list of Persons in that country using EF inheritance
    // return list of persons
}
```

The list of persons, contains objects that are *either* of type `DanishPerson` or `BritishPerson`. Depending on the type, I need to display the right ViewModel in my UI. So if the list contains danish persons of type `DanishPerson`, I need to display one UI that will show the danish specific properties (and more).

Now my question is how you do this the best way? I guess that I could always use an if/else using `typeof`, but I was hoping for a more elegant, and maybe generic way?
I was thinking that there might be some patterns for doing this as it seems like a common problem to me, when dealing with specializations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Dictionary to map behaviour according to the person type.
Better yet create a Ibehaviour interface and inherit two classes from it one for British and one for Danish and encapsulate the different behaviour between the two.

When adding another person type requires creating a behaviour class and updating the Dictionary.

Create a dictionary (private member of the class):

```
Dictionary<Type, IBehaviour> mapper = new Dictionary<Type, IBehaviour>()
{
   {typeof(BritishPerson), new BritishPersonBehaviour()},
   {typeof(DanishPerson), new DanishPersonBehaviour()}
};
```

In the code:

```
Person person = ...
var behaviour = mapper[person.GetType()];
behaviour.ShowUI(); //or something like this
```

Comment: Thank you Dror. Can you give me a short implementation example? Or maybe you know of an article describing it?

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems like a good solution and I would try and implement it. Do you know of other ways to do it that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `Dictionary<K, V>` to store the mappings between the country codes and the associated class type and then use LINQ method `OfType` to obtain just the instances of the type associated to the provided country code.

Answer (score 0):

If the List object is homogenous (i.e it's always either populated with only Danish or British person objects then this little LINQ tidbit will work:

```
var list = GetPersonsByCountry(1);
if (list.OfType<BritishPerson>().Any())
     ShowBritishUI();
else
     ShowDanishUI();
```